# How to extract the hidden vector (the output of the ReLU after the third encoder layer) as the image representation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder

I am implementing an autoencoder using the Fashion Mnsit dataset. The code for the encoder-

```
class MNISTClassifier(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MNISTClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = Sequential([
            layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu"),
            layers.Dense(64, activation = "relu"),
            layers.Dense(32, activation = "relu")
        ])
        
        self.decoder = Sequential([
            layers.Dense(64, activation = "relu"), 
            layers.Dense(128, activation= "relu"),
            layers.Dense(784, activation= "relu")
        ])
        
    def call(self, x):
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        return decoded
    
autoencoder = MNISTClassifier()
```

now I want to train an SVM classifier on the image representations extracted from the above autoencoder mean
Once the above fully-connected autoencoder is trained, for each image, I want to extract the 32-
dimensional hidden vector (the output of the ReLU after the third encoder layer) as the
image representation and then train a linear SVM classifier on the training images of fashion mnist based on the 32-
dimensional features.

How to extract the output 32-
dimensional hidden vector??

Thanks in Advance!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You can use `enc_outputs = classifier.encoder.predict( images )` where `classifier` is an instance of `MNISTClassifier`.

Comment: and if I want output from any intermediate layer like from a layer with 64 neurons then what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use **Functional API** in order to define multiple outputs of your model because of a more clear code. However, you can do this with **Sequential** model by getting the output of any layer you want and add to your model's output.

Print your `model.summary()` and check your layers to find which layer you want to branch. You can access each layer's output by it's index with `model.layers[index].output` .

Then you can create a multi-output model of the layers you want, like this:

```
 third_layer = model.layers[2]
 last_layer = model.layers[-1]
 my_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=(third_layer.output, last_layer.output))
```

Then, you can access the outputs of both of layers you have defined:

```
third_layer_predict, last_layer_predict = my_model.predict(X_test)
```